# connecting a hp laptop charger adapter three wire output to a two wire cable

Tags: dc, charger, adapter, laptop

My laptop charger adapter broke and I a have this other old adaptor in the house. They both have the same voltage(19V) and 1.58A. The first adapter(The one that broke) has three wires (black, white, and red) going out which then connect to the laptop charger pin. The second adapter however, has three wires going out. I have read that an extra wire is used as some kind of a sensor. In another forum someone identified the sensor wire and left it out in the connection. **What does the three wires represent each(which is neutral or positive)?**

I simply need a easy fix for my charger. While you attempt to answer please note that I do not have a multimeter or any tool for checking current and voltage except for a tester screw driver and that Except for high school physics I do not know anything else in electricity. I also hope that this is the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use a multimeter to verify that you made the right connections regarding + and -, you risk **damaging the laptop**.

Please consider if that is an acceptable risk to you. It is much less risk to simply get a new adapter. New adapters are almost always cheaper than having your laptop repaired.

The 3rd wire might be used for adapter identification. If your laptop needs that identification then **it will not charge the battery** when you're using the 2-wire adapter.

Again a reason to get the proper charger and not fiddle around with this.

Comment: This is very helpful. I guess the your caution really sank in. I'll take it to a real electrician to figure it out. Then I'll post the findings. Or I'll just have to buy a new one.

Comment: Real electricians charge more for looking at something than the price of a proper adapter (at least in my country). If the electrician is a lot cheaper, I would doubt his/her abilities. You can also by an "HP compatible" charger, these are usually much cheaper and should work just as well as the HP branded ones.

Answer (score 0):

According to the convention, **Black** one is neutral.

And I'm assuming **Red**(which is mostly used) wire is positive. You can test it with tester. If you put the plug in power line  and test the red one, tester light should on.